# Errors in Karma & Jasmine tests after Angular upgrade to 17 version

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

After upgrade Angular to version 17 I decided to upgrade also Karma and Jasmine to newest versions (Karma-Jasmine v. 5.1.0, Jasmine-Core v. 4.5.0).

After this upgrade I figured out that some tests doesn't works properly.

Below test has problem, that it pass when it's run separately but when I run all tests it fails...

```
let actions: Observable<any>
describe('YourEffects', () => {
  let effects: YourEffects;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        StoreModule.forRoot({
          myReducers: combineReducers(reducers)
        }),
      ],
      providers: [
        YourEffects,
        YourService,
        provideMockStore(() => actions),
      ],
    });

    effects = TestBed.inject(YourEffects);
  });

  it('should load SomeInfo action', () => {
    const action = new myActions.GetPersonCars();
    const completion = new myActions.LoadPersonOrder();

    const spy = spyOn(service, 'getPersonByName').and.returnValue(of(TEST_PERSON));

    actions$ = hot('-a', { a: action });
    const expected = cold('-b', { b: completion });

    effects.get$.subscribe(a => expect(a).toEqual(completion));

    expect(effects.get$).toBeObservable(expected);
  });
});
```

does anyone know when can be a problem?

Comment: Same issue no luck yet

Comment: The problem could be related to `actions` or `actions$` that may be changed by another test inside your test suite. You could also try to replace `(...).and.returnValue(of(TEST_PERSON))`  by `(...).and.resolveTo(TEST_PERSON)` .

Comment: Did you find the root cause of this? We had the same issue and fixed this by cloning objects that were used as test data so the reference is gone. But we want to know what changed in Angular 17 / Jasmine update that suddenly causes test data to be accessed by reference...